# Configuring toString via a public static variable

Tags: java, static

Sometimes I need `toString()` to be quite verbose, normally I don't. It can't be nicely solved by using other methods as `toString()` is what gets shown in debugger (and also in the logs unless I call some method explicitly). As nobody should ever rely on its behavior, I wonder if the following is acceptable

```
public static boolean volatile verboseToString;

public String toString() {
    return toString(verboseToString);
}

public String toString(boolean verbose) {
    if (verbose) {
        return longDescription();
    } else {
        return shortDescription();
    }
}
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Just had another thought, are you concatenating using `+` or `StringBuilder`? It might make a difference if the verbosity is expensive and is constantly being created. But may not be needed as it could be optimized by the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that using such a global variable is fine. As nobody should ever rely on the behavior of `toString()`, it can't be a problem. Instead of the global public variable I'll use a method so it looks a bit cleaner.

It's ugly, but it does what I need and there's no nice way.

Answer (score 6):

You could try to use Logger level to control verbose mode.

```
public String toString() {
    return toString(logger.isDebugEnabled());
}

public String toString(boolean verbose) {
    if (verbose) {
        return longDescription();
    } else {
        return shortDescription();
    }
}
```

Advantage of this approach is that it's easier to control toString() verbosity level - simply by config file for you logging framework, JMX extension, ...

This could also give you more flexibility - based on log level (INFO, DEBUG, TRACE), your could control how much information you put into toString().

Comment: This makes sense, although it couples two thing together: the decision if there's an output at all and the the decision how detailed it is. So you can end up with either a long output or none at all.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I use `toDebugString()` to prevent misuse for others that may be using this class (or even myself down the line). It has clear intent/purpose (self documenting) without requiring extra thinking to read the javadoc.

On related note, you may find this [reference](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=341DEC0F4A83C47D92FB7A44D2298BF3?Id=55) (A collection of "best" java practices) on implementing `toString()` helpful as well.

Comment: But is there any way to make my debugger use `toDebugString()`? I don't think so, and I don't want to repeat the explicit method call in each logging/debugging statement. I'm afraid I didn't formulate my question clearly enough...

Comment: Typically when you're debugging, you'll be using an IDE to step through your code -- debugging vis-a-vis print statements is not good practice since it could be an improper use of the API and thus hidden from your `toString()` method. But, you could also decorate it with an interface with something like `IsDebuggable` and use an intermediary (processor) to do handle it. Then you would implement `IsDebuggable` to all classes that you'd want to see as verbose (enforcing a contract) and then use it as such: `processClass(IsDebuggable someClass) { someClass.toDebugString(); }` )

Answer (score 2):

It reminds me  [Test Logic in Production](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Logic%20in%20Production.html) chapter from the *XUnit Test Patterns* book.

*Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 10: Always override toString* suggest that,

> When practical, the `toString` method should return all of the interesting
>   information contained in the object [...]

So, I'd use the `toString` method for only logging and debugging (whether it's verbose or not) and use another methods where specific formats are required.

Comment: Sure, the problem is that "all of the interesting information" is actually very long, and sometimes I need "the most important information" only, depending on what I'm currently doing. As an example imagine "class Person". When working with a single person, you may want to see everything; when looking at a list of  tens of them, the name alone is nearly too much.